# PyQt 5 update list model

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qml, pyqt5

I am trying to update listview model in QML quick controls with python. Every item in this model contains `address` and status `property`. Right now my code is this:

ListModel:

```
class ServersModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ServersModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list = []
        for address, status in (
            ("server 1", "green"),
            ("server 2", "green"),
            ("server 3", "red")):
            self.list.append(server(address, status))

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.list)

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole: #show just the name
            person = self.list[index.row()]
            return QVariant(person.name)
        elif role == Qt.UserRole:  #return the whole python object
            person = self.list[index.row()]
            return person
        return QVariant()

    def removeRow(self, position):
        self.list = self.list[:position] + self.list[position+1:]
        self.reset()
```

ServerObject:

```
class server(object):
    '''
    a custom data structure, for example purposes
    '''
    def __init__(self, address, status):
        self.address = address
        self.status = status
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s\n%s"% (self.address, self.status)
```

Python connection handler:

```
class ServersListViewHandler(QObject):

def __init__(self):
    QObject.__init__(self)

listLoaded = pyqtSignal(QAbstractListModel, arguments=['model'])
data_changed = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)

# Slot for detecting clicks in listView
@pyqtSlot(str)
def listViewItemClicked(self, name):
    self.listLoaded.emit(ServersModel())
```

And this is my connectin at qml:

```
Connections {
        target: serversListViewHandler

        onListLoaded: {
            serversListView.model = model
        }
    }
```

Address property should go to text as value and status is color of circle. This works fine if I implement model directly to QML but I want to update it dynamically and load it form python. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I am probably doing it totally wrong but there are almost none tutorial or references about pyqt 5

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar experiment at the moment. I succeeded doing this by using dedicated role names for columns (in my case in the list view). 
For your example this would kinda look like this:

```
class ServersModel(QAbstractListModel):

     AddressRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
     StatusRole = Qt.UserRole + 2

    _roles = {AddressRole: b"address", StatusRole: b"status"}
    ...

    def roleNames(self):
        return self._roles

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == AddressRole: #show just the name
            person = self.list[index.row()]
            return QVariant(person.name)
        elif role == StatusRole:  #return the whole python object
            person = self.list[index.row()]
            return person
        return QVariant()
```

Though this may only target the displaying part, not the complete update procedure. Would be interesting to see the QML where you access the model.
Also I'm not really sure if there is some kind of best practice for this kind of thing.